# Strapi Loading Error after creating a component in content type

Tags: react-native, strapi

When trying to run strapi backend, build context and admin creation is successfull but it doesn't load. An error shows up "⠴ Loading Strapi[ERROR]  There seems to be an unexpected error, try again with --debug for more information ". Everything was working fine before creating a new component in content type.

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐│                                                                                                                                                      ││   SyntaxError: C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\src\components\course-description\course-description.json: Unexpected       ││   token  in JSON at position 0                                                                                                                       ││   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)                                                                                                                        ││   at Object._readFile (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\jsonfile\index.js:25:16)                               ││   at async loadFiles (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\load\load-files.js:20:13)           ││   at async Object.loadComponents                                                                                                                     ││   (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\core\loaders\components.js:12:15)                      ││   at async Strapi.loadComponents (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:313:23)       ││   at async Promise.all (index 6)                                                                                                                     ││   at async Strapi.register (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:334:5)              ││   at async Strapi.load (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\strapi\dist\Strapi.js:418:5)                  ││   at async Object.develop                                                                                                                            ││   (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\admin\dist\_chunks\index-1a74fa41.js:1241:28)                      ││   at async develop (C:\Users\Manuj98\Desktop\expoGo\Xacademy\Xacademy-backend\node_modules\@strapi\admin\dist\_chunks\develop-4d25a6e0.js:52:5)
```

Comment: might be some build issue, suggest you to build and restart the server

"npm run build" then 
"npm run develop"